# Webservice or Oracle DMS?

Tags: android, ios, oracle, web-services

I am at a crossroads in choosing how I should access my database from an Android / iOS application. The following is the majority of what i plan on doing in hte application. Any help is appreciated, as I am completely lost as to which route to take - Webservice or DMS.

- Login / Registration
- OTP (One-time-pin, cannot use app without code sent to mobile)
- Using maps to display locations, distance from them, etc (all location GPS coordinates are in the database already)
- Notifications / reminders (e.g. take medication)

Thats the jist of it - I just want to know what would be better, a webservice or oracle DMS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting mobile devices directly to DATABASE is not recommended. It is technically possible but there are serious security implications, not to mention performance, battery life, etc.

So Creating a REST Webservices are far better for mobile applications.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to say, not directly to the database. But yes I understand what you are saying. I forgot to mention specifically that I am connecting to Oracle DB, if that might make a difference

Comment: Would a sync solution (DMS) not be better for it though?

Comment: REST will be better, because I didn't use DMS in my 4 years of career no body recommended to use it. Evan Facebook , gmail etc are using REST API for mobile applications